# Fetching data from Firebase into listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase and I want that data to be printed in my `listview.builder`.

**Here is my code:-**

```
StreamBuilder(
       stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("passwordProfile")
              .snapshots(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }

       if (snapshot.data.documents.lenght == 0) {
             return Text("no data");
       }

       return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.lenght,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: snapshot.data.documents[index].data("url")),
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["url"],
              );
      });
}),
```

**And below is a picture:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

From the picture you can observe that documents is not being recognized so help there.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify SteamBuilder return type i-e Querysnapshot here's the example of your code

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("passwordProfile")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  final userSnapshot = snapshot.data?.docs;
                  if (userSnapshot!.isEmpty) {
                    return const Text("no data");
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: userSnapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            child: userSnapshot[index]["url"],
                          ),
                          title: userSnapshot[index]["url"],
                        );
                      });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you check null, you can add `!` like `snapshot.data!`

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
  final data = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>?;
  if (data == null) {
    return Text("no data");
  }
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          // leading:
          //     CircleAvatar(child: data[index].data("url")),
          title: Text("${data[index].data["url"]}"),
        );
      });
}),
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Follow update one, and what dataType are you getting from stream Builder