# Error when fetching data from from firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I get this Error when fetching data from a field in firebase collection
the field is an array of the user orders

Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic,
Widget>'

```
StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          //print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: ReusibleText(text: 'Your store is empty'),
              ));
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      // final List orders=[];
                      // for(var order in snapshot.data[index]['orders']){
                      //   orders.add(order);
                      // }
                      return snapshot.data.docs[index]['orders']
                          .map<Widget>((order) => Column(
                                children: [
                                  AllOrdersWidget(
                                    userId: order['userId'],
                                    productId: order['productId'],
                                    userName: order['userName'],
                                    imageUrl: order['imageUrl'],
                                    quantity: int.parse(order['quantity']),
                                    date: order['orderDate'],
                                    address: order['address'],
                                    orderId: order['orderId'],
                                    price: order['price'],
                                    totalPrice: order['totalPrice'],
                                  ),
                                  Divider(),
                                ],
                              ));
                    }),
              );
            } else {
              return ReusibleText(text: "Error");
            }
          }
          return ReusibleText(text: "Something went wrong");
        },
      ),
```

Comment: why are you mapping when you're using a builder? Since, you're mapping, it'll return an iterable list while the builder expects a widget.

Comment: can you add your api response?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73439313/fetching-data-from-firebase-into-listview-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your `MappedListIterable` into a `List` by calling `.toList()` on it.
Then you will receive `Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'List<Widget>` because your `.map` is returning a `List` of `Column` which is a List, when you should be returning a single `Widget`. To fix this you can change your return to this:

```
return Column( // <-- Wrap your map with a Column and use the spread operator to insert all the map elements into the Column children.
      children: [
        ...snapshot.data.docs[index]['orders'].map<Widget>(
          (order) => ...[
            AllOrdersWidget(
              userId: order['userId'],
              productId: order['productId'],
              userName: order['userName'],
              imageUrl: order['imageUrl'],
              quantity: int.parse(order['quantity']),
              date: order['orderDate'],
              address: order['address'],
              orderId: order['orderId'],
              price: order['price'],
              totalPrice: order['totalPrice'],
            ),
            Divider(),
          ],
        ).toList(), // <-- Add the toList()
      ],
    );
```

Comment: this will work but the list will have total ``snapshot.data.docs[index]['orders'] * 10`` items. If you notice listview builder  is provided a length of constant 10 causing it to loop 10 times and each time orders are mapped.

Comment: now i get this Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: @OMiShah but it will loop different indexes up to 10, therefore it will be accessing different orders for every document, none of them should be repeated, right?